# Clarification on chinese remainder theorem for ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~rdwillar/Courses/PM701/lecture_09_11.pdf

I am not able to understand why  $$(r_1 +\cdots + r_{i-1} + r_{i+1} +\cdots + r_k) - a_i \in A_i$$ 
in the last line of **Theorem 17.5 (Chinese remainder theorem)** of this link.

Comment: the link is broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By assumption (see the previous sentence) you have $r_i \in A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \cdots\cap A_{i-1} \cap A_{i + 1} \cap \cdots \cap A_k$. So in particular, $r_1 \in A_i, r_2 \in A_i, \dots r_{i-1} \in A_i, r_{i+1} \in A_i, \dots r_k \in A_i$. So you have $r^\prime = r_1 + r_2 \cdots + r_{i-1} + r_{i+1} + \cdots + r_k \in A_i$. Since $A_i$ is an ideal and $a_i, r^\prime \in A_i$ you also have $r^\prime - a_i \in A_i$.

Comment: @Faisal You're welcome : )